# How javascript is managing Object property name as Object which changes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I was looking in docs on MDN and found that Object poperty names can be Object(which will be converted to string). I wrote a simple code to test it out and it worked but later changing the obj which is being assigned as a key to main Object,should change the resulted key (string representation) thus the Main object property should not be accesible with new object but It is accesible.

I wanna know how javascript it managing this?

```js
var objee = {};
var rajat = "me";
var rand = Math.random();
var ob = new Object();

objee[ob] = "hey";


console.log(ob,objee[ob]);//javascript is converting the Object key to string using Object.toString().

ob.name = "rajat";

// Why this property is still accesible if the "ob" has changed now..and resulted string is changed,thus key changed?

console.log(ob,objee[ob]);
```

I know this is question is very confusing..Hope you will understand.

Comment: This is not a good idea.Object to string produces "[object Object]". Doesn't matter what object is used will be same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object might have changed, but its string representation has not:

```js
var ob = new Object();
console.log(ob.toString());
ob.name = "foo";
console.log(ob.toString());
```

… so the property name being referenced by it is also unchanged.

Comment: No. It just is. (Using an object as a property names in the first place seems like a bad idea though).

Comment: So this will be same for any object and any workarround for this?

Answer (score 0):

As you have commented, the name of the key referenced by the ob object is the value of ob.toString(). When you call this, it will return '[object Object]'

This means that the key name is '[object Object]'. This will not change even if you change the value of ob.name as ob.toString() still outputs [object Object]

If you call console.log(ob), you will see the property name output as above.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) article for more details